# Polars: returning dict from `apply` function - key order does not match return_dtype declaration?

Tags: python-polars

With this dtype defined (note reverse-alpha field order):

```py
Similarity = Struct([
    Field('zavg', pl.Float64),
    Field('ystd', pl.Float64),
    Field('xbase_indices', pl.List(pl.Int64))
])
```

When I run this `apply` returning a fixed `dict` that matches `Similarity` in keys, type, and order:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({'x': [0, 1]})
df.with_columns((
    pl.col('x')
    .apply(lambda d: {'zavg':1.1, 'ystd': 0.1, 'xbase_indices': [2]},
           return_dtype=Similarity)
    .alias(col+'_Blah')
    for col in ['item_1A', 'item_7']))
```

I get this `SchemaError` with key order mismatch (note key order):
**SchemaError: expected output type**

```
Struct([
  Field { name: "zavg", dtype: Float64 }, 
  Field { name: "ystd", dtype: Float64 }, 
  Field { name: "xbase_indices", dtype: List(Int64) }])
```

**got** (note alphabetical key order)

```
Struct([
  Field { name: "xbase_indices", dtype: List(Int64) }, 
  Field { name: "ystd", dtype: Float64 }, 
  Field { name: "zavg", dtype: Float64 }])
```

**set `return_dtype` to the proper datatype**

If I remove the `return_dtype` it works. Further experiments suggest Polars is reading the dict keys in alphabetical order.

Expected? How should I handle this?

Comment: There does appear to be a sort happening. It probably needs to be [filed as a bug.](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/)

Comment: Just did that, thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/commit/600c325d442e153882a4f9cc655d79c39ec0eb00 fixes this.