# Column ordering when mapping function

Tags: python, python-polars

With python 3.10.4, this:

```
df = polars.DataFrame(dict(
  j=numpy.tile([1, 0, 0], 3),
  k=numpy.random.randint(10, 99, 9)
  ))

def f(ks):
  return dict(
    u=ks[0] + 100,
    i=ks[1] + 200,
    o=ks[2] + 300,
    )

dfj = (df
  .groupby(polars.col('j').cumsum(), maintain_order=True)
  .agg(
    polars.col('k').apply(f).alias('k')
    )
  .unnest('k')
  )
print(polars.__version__)
print(dfj)
```

produces different column ordering in polars 0.18.9:

```
0.18.9
 j (i64)  i (i64)  o (i64)  u (i64)
 1        222      382      147
 2        285      315      119
 3        274      326      189
shape: (3, 4)
```

and polars 0.18.10 (and apparently later - 0.18.13 works as 0.18.10):

```
0.18.10
 j (i64)  u (i64)  i (i64)  o (i64)
 1        147      222      382
 2        119      285      315
 3        189      274      326
shape: (3, 4)
```

I couldn't find anything in the docs that says that the order is guaranteed, so I have three related questions:

- Can others reproduce this?
- Is the order guaranteed or is this just an implementation detail?
- If not guaranteed, is there a way to do what I'm after that guarantees the order or do I need to reorder columns manually afterwards?

Comment: The order changed because https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/10128 was fixed. Original SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76783991/polars-returning-dict-from-apply-function-key-order-does-not-match-return-d

Comment: Ah, thanks @jqurious! I'll close this as a duplicate.